# how to see two or more layout with android?

Tags: android, layout, itemizedoverlay

hello
I got a project that I need to add one or more layout to my existent layout.
The problem is that I can see only my last layout .
I am using overlay's vector and i'm asure that is not the way to solve this problem
I will be glad if some one will give me some clue how to solve this problem
thank you

Answer (score 0):

By using the  tag in your original xml file you can add a part of layout to original layout.